# Object type is not callable in is dataframe where I want to remove rows based on a list of variables

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

Within my data set on US elections I have a bunch of data in my file which I would like to remove at a row level based on the variable in the "party" column.
Sample of my data set;

| state | county | candidate | party | total_votes | won |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Delaware | Kent County | Joe Biden | DEM | 44552 | True |
| Delaware | Kent County | Donald Trump | REP | 41009 | False |
| Delaware | Kent County | Jo Jorgensen | LIB | 1044 | False |
| Delaware | Kent County | Howie Hawkins | GRN | 420 | False |
| Delaware | New Castle County | Joe Biden | DEM | 195034 | True |
| Delaware | New Castle County | Donald Trump | REP | 88364 | False |
| Delaware | New Castle County | Jo Jorgensen | LIB | 2953 | False |
| Delaware | New Castle County | Howie Hawkins | GRN | 1282 | False |
| Delaware | Sussex County | Donald Trump | REP | 71230 | True |

For all rows where the party value is not "DEM" or "REP" I want to delete these.
Using the following code I extracted all unique party values;

```
    uniqueParty = df['party'].unique()
    print(uniqueParty)
['DEM' 'REP' 'LIB' 'GRN' 'WRI' 'PSL' 'IND' 'ALI' 'CST' 'ASP' 'OTH' 'UTY'
 'LLC' 'SWP' 'BAR' 'PRO' 'NON' 'PRG' 'UNA' 'BMP' 'GOP' 'BFP' 'APV' 'IAP'
 'LLP' 'SEP']
```

I then created a list removing DEM and REP;

```
uniqueParty2 =['LIB', 'GRN', 'WRI', 'PSL', 'IND', 'ALI', 'CST', 'ASP', 'OTH', 'UTY',
 'LLC', 'SWP', 'BAR', 'PRO', 'NON', 'PRG', 'UNA', 'BMP', 'GOP', 'BFP', 'APV', 'IAP',
 'LLP', 'SEP']


print(type(uniqueParty2))
```

This is a list I then want to pass through the following code to remove the rows as required;

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(uniqueParty2()))
df = df[df.column_name.isin(uniqueParty2) == False]
```

This is failing and the message I get is "TypeError: 'list' object is not callable"
I have tried a tuple and a string type in the code but same message - these types are not callable in the code.

Comment: Show the actual error message with traceback.  The error tells me that some variable is a python `list`, which cannot be use as though it were a function.  That question is, what variable?

Comment: Looks like a typo, ref my answer

Comment: I have removed the parentheses as suggested and I returned an error, albeit a different one this time around.
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'column_name'
Do I need to pass the column name into this statement - 'party'?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's because you have parentheses after `uniqueParty2` in `df = pd.DataFrame(list(uniqueParty2()))`. uniqueParty2 is a list, and parentheses tells Python to try call it as a function.

Answer (score 0):

I actually approached this from a different angle. I used the drop function for any values that were not the values I required and that way I didn't need to use a list to get the desired result.

```
df = df.drop(df[(df.party != 'REP') & (df.party != 'DEM')].index)
```